# Find all directories and files of your laptop

Tags: python, linux, windows, filesystems

How can we write code in Python​ to find all file system including files from root  to each and every file of the current computer system.

Comment: [Have](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk) [you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/120656/directory-listing-in-python) [tried](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/973473/getting-a-list-of-all-subdirectories-in-the-current-directory) [looking](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/800197/get-all-of-the-immediate-subdirectories-in-python) [anywhere?](https://www.google.com/search?q=Python%E2%80%8B+to+find+all+directories)

Comment: I don't think the OP realized how to apply that solution to all directories @tzaman

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `os.walk` method. Here is an example:

```
# !/usr/bin/python

import os
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(".", topdown=False):
    for name in files:
        print(os.path.join(root, name))
    for name in dirs:
        print(os.path.join(root, name))
```

copied from http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_walk.htm

See the full documentation: https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk

Comment: `os.walk("\\")` works fine too

Comment: Thanks for replying @swoogan. I want to find each and every files of the computer not just a current working directory.

Comment: @RohanDongre that is exactly what `os.walk` does. Please refer to the documentation I linked: "Generate the file names in a directory tree by walking the tree either top-down or bottom-up"

Comment: Thanks @Swoogan I'll refer it.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the `os` module.
`os.chdir(path)` changes the working dir.
`os.listdir()` lists all the directories in your working dir.

If you wanna find *all* the directories of your current system, you need to iterate through your system using for example BFS search (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search).