# How can I make an array of subdirectories in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, directory, operating-system, sys

I want to make an array of subdirectories in Python. Here is an example layout and model list I would like to obtain.

```
                             Root
                              |
                         directories
                            /    \
                      subdir_1... subdir_n
```

Hence from the root, I would like to run a program that will make a list of all the subdirectories. That way if I were to write:

```
print(List_of_Subdirectories)
```

Where List_of_Subdirectories is the list of appended directories. I would obtain the output:

```
[subdir_1, subdir_2, ... , subdir_n]
```

In essence, I would like to achieve the same results as if I were to hard code every directory into a list. For example:

```
List_of_Subdirectories = ["subdir_1", "subdir_2", ... , "subdir_n"]
```

Where subdir_n denotes an arbitrary nth directory.

Unlike other posts here on stack overflow, I would like the list to contain just the directory names without tuples or paths.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get all of the immediate subdirectories in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/800197/how-to-get-all-of-the-immediate-subdirectories-in-python)

Comment: Hi @PeterWood, I looked at that post and I didn't quite get the help I wanted from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you *just* want the directory names, you can use [os.walk](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) to do this:

os.walk(directory)
will yield a tuple for each subdirectory. The first entry in the 3-tuple is a directory name. You can wrap this in a function to simply return the list of directory names like so:

```
def list_paths(path):
    directories = [x[1] for x in os.walk(path)]
    non_empty_dirs = [x for x in directories if x] # filter out empty lists
    return [item for subitem in non_empty_dirs for item in subitem] # flatten the list
```

should give you all of the directories.

Comment: Is there any way I can avoid getting the tuples? I would like to have a list with just the directory names. It would work the exact same way as if I were to hard code each directory name myself like L = ["dir1", "dir2", "dir3", ...etc]

Comment: The list comprehension given will yield a list of strings. You can wrap this in a function where the parameter given is a directory path and the list is returned?

Comment: @fwubb I've updated my answer to be a function instead :)

Comment: When I do that, it prepends the path onto the directory name. How would I be able to only work with the directory name?

Comment: @fwubb I've updated my answer to print _all_ directory names from a given path (including duplicates).

Answer (score -1):

If all you want is a list of the subdirectories of an specified directory, all you need is [os.listdir](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir) and a filter to display only directories.

It's as simple as:

```py
List_of_Subdirectories = list(filter(os.path.isdir, os.listdir()))
print(List_of_Subdirectories)
```

The return from `os.listdir` is a list containing the names of all the available elements in the specified directory (or `.` by default), directories and files. We filter only the directories using `os.path.isdir`. Then, as you want a `list`, we explicitly convert the filtered result.

You wouldn't be able to `print` the filtered result, but you would be able to iterate over it. The snippet below would achieve the same result as the one avobe.

```py
directory_elements = filter(os.path.isdir, os.listdir())
List_of_Subdirectories = []
for element in directory_elements:
    List_of_Subdirectories.append(element)
print(List_of_Subdirectories)
```

Comment: This answer only gives the directory names at a given level, rather than all children of a path.

Comment: And that is exactly what the question asked for. Or at least what I understand from what's written.

Comment: I messed up on my question initially, so that probably answered the right question before I edited.

Comment: Well, in case someone else comes here looking for this info, there are two available ways to do it :)