# Return files only from specific folder

Tags: python

I wrote a function in Python, that must return file from specific folder and all subfolders. File name taken from function parameter:

```
def ReturnFile(fileName)
  return open("C:\\folder\\" + fileName,"r")
```

But as `fileName` you can pass for example: `"..\\Windows\\passwords.txt`" or some unicode symbols for dots.

How to fix it? Some RegExp maybe?

Comment: What do you want to do? Check that the string given as filename is a valid filename?

Comment: I want that program can return files from only one folder(and subfolders), and be shure that nobody can give parametr with ex. ".." and read all files on server.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/120656/directory-listing-in-python, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/973473/getting-a-list-of-all-subdirectories-in-the-current-directory

Answer (score 4):

The [`os.path.normpath`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.normpath) function normalizes a given path py resolving things like "..". Then you can check if the resulting path is in the expected directory:

```
def ReturnFile(fileName)
  norm = os.path.abspath("C:\\folder\\" + fileName)
  if not norm.startswith("C:\\folder\\"):
    raise Exception("Invalid filename specified")
  return open(norm,"r")
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
import os

_BASE_PATH= "C:\\folder\\"

def return_file(file_name):
    "Return File Object from Base Path named `file_name`"
    os.path.normpath(file_name).split(os.path.sep)[-1]
    return(open(_BASE_PATH+file_name))
```

Comment: On windows: `>>> r'../../AUTOEXEC.BAT'.split(os.path.sep)[-1]` Results in: `'../../AUTOEXEC.BAT'`.

Comment: Yeah that is true, when using raw text split may not work as expected. I've updated my answer, thanks.