# Python: Rename multiple files starting with a "#"

Tags: python, directory, subdirectory, renaming

I want to rename multiple files in a directory, if they start with "#", for example:

#222_message_split ->               222_message_split

#013_message_split2 ->                 013_message_split2

**edit: I tried this:**

```
for filename in os.listdir(PATH):
    if filename.startswith("#"):
        os.rename(filename, filename[1:])
```

**edit2: with the help of pstatix I got the code to work, now checking subdirectories for "#_____" files as well.**

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(PATH):
for dir in dirs:
    if dir.startswith("#"):
        org_fp = os.path.join(root, dir)
        new_fp = os.path.join(root, dir[1:])
        os.rename(org_fp, new_fp)
```

Comment: Okay. Well, what have you tried?

Comment: add your code to the qusetion

Comment: I edited my question and added the code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close, although your indentation was off:

**Original Question:**

```
for filename in os.listdir(PATH):
    if filename.startswith("#"):
        org_fp = os.path.join(PATH, filename)
        new_fp = os.path.join(PATH, filename[1:])
        os.rename(org_fp, new_fp)
```

`os.listdir()` doesn't return the full path even if `PATH` was a full path; only basenames are listed. So you must provide a full path for `os.rename()` to function correctly; done using `os.path.join()`.

**Comment Requested Update:**

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(PATH):
    for file in files:
        if file.startswith("#"):
            org_fp = os.path.join(root, file)
            new_fp = os.path.join(root, file[1:])
            os.rename(org_fp, new_fp)
```

Take a look at the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) and this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2922783/how-do-you-walk-through-the-directories-using-python) for information.

Comment: that works perfect thank you a lot pstatix! unfortunately I have to bother you even more, because I would like my code to traverse every subfolder as well, what do I have to add to my code to achieve this?

Comment: again, thanks a lot, I will try this updated code and check the docs ect., glad that you helped me!

Comment: @DanielSeidl You selected as the answer to your question; did you verify it worked?

Comment: did that before reading the update, since it is the answer to the initial question I asked. Until now I can't get it to work, but I am still trying to get into the docs and the post you linked, since I am coding for about a month now only. Will try to understand what you did, and what "walk()" really does :)
basically I have a directory containing folders, which are containing subfolders and so on, in some there are files/folders starting with the # -> the thing I want removed.

Comment: @DanielSeidl `os.walk()` returns a tuple of 3 items. The docs describes what it does and provides an example. Should have everything you need. When you get it working or have more questions, come back and ask or select as answer.

Comment: I got it to work now, had to change for file in files to for dir in dirs, and change the file to dir in both the org_fp and the new_fp. Thank you for your fast answers :)

Comment: @DanielSeidl Not sure I follow, can you post the updated block with the changes you just mentioned in your original post?

Comment: I edited the original post, now showing the solution to my problem.

Comment: @nEWBOB (name change?). So the items you wanted to rename were directories and not files?

Comment: yes name change, was a bit to fast when registering I guess. Thats correct, after solving the problem I realised my question was a bit misleading, hence the "for file in files" is not wrong, but an initial mistake from my side, since I really meant directories.