# Rename Single .txt File In Multiple Subdirectories

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have ~60 subdirectories in a single directory. Each of these contain thousands of files, but they all contain a file named `test_all_results.txt`.

What I would like to do is to rename each `test_all_results.txt` file so that it now has the name:

`foldername_all_results.txt`

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Did you attempt any code for this?

Comment: I am not super experienced in python, so I spent the last two hours trying to find an analogous answer with no result.

Comment: Please show an effort to solve this yourself, and we can help you with any specific issue you encounter.

Comment: Did you look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html, this might have the functions you want! Try this out, and show us your work! And we can help on top of it

Comment: [How to go through directories](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2922878/10366273) and [how to rename a file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2491232/10366273).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to rename a file using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491222/how-to-rename-a-file-using-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easily accomplished using Python `os` interface.

Assuming you are currently in the main directory:

```
import os
#get a list of all sub directories
subdir = os.listdir()

for dir in subdir:       
    if os.path.isdir(dir): #check if directory          
        os.chdir(dir) #move to sub directory
        os.rename('test_all_results.txt', 'foldername_all_results.txt')            
        os.chdir('..') #return to main directory
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

(change your code accordingly)

```
import os

# current directory is the target
direct = "."
for path, dirs, files in os.walk(direct):
    for f in files:
        if os.path.splitext(f)[0] == "test_all_results.txt":
            os.rename(os.path.join(path, f), os.path.join(path, "foldername_all_results.txt"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using python in Linux, make this:

```
import os
os.system("mv old_name.txt new_name.txt")
```

You can automatize with a loop, renaming all filenames.

Answer (score 1):

There's an answer that tells you to use the [`os.system()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system) method, if you do decide to call Linux commands from Python, I'd advise that you use the [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module instead.

Here's how you'd run the `mv` command with two arguments using `subprocess.call`:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call(["mv", "filename.txt", "new-name.txt"])
```

**INFO:** here's an old (but relevant) article that explains [why it's dangerous to use these methods](https://www.kevinlondon.com/2015/07/26/dangerous-python-functions.html).

Good luck.