# Scanning a directory to list the name of all files

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

I have a big folder in which there are many subfolders. Each of those subfolders can also have some subfolders ( number can be different ) in it. This goes on for some levels. And in the end, there is a text file. How can I make a python program that traverses the entire directory as deep as it goes and prints the name of the text file? In simpler terms, I want to navigate through the directory as long as there are no more sub-directories?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you walk through the directories using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2922783/how-do-you-walk-through-the-directories-using-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `os.walk`.

For instance, creating a deep hierarchy like

```
$ mkdir -p a/b/c/d/e/f/g
$ touch a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h.txt
```

and running

```
import os
for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('.'):
    for filename in filenames:
         filepath = os.path.join(dirname, filename)
         print(filepath)
```

yields

```
./a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h.txt
```

– do what you will with `filepath`.

Another option, if you're using Python 3.5 or newer (and you probably should be) is `glob.glob()` with a recursive pattern:

```
>>> print(glob.glob("./**/*.txt", recursive=True))
['./a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h.txt']
```