# find command listing results in directory order

Tags: linux

I am trying to use the find command to find all files 'M*' from my working directory and display results in directory order.

Instead it keeps displaying results in sorted order which causes some deeper directories to be listed first because they are alphabetically in order.

```
$ find -name 'M*'
./MyFourth
./s/MyFirst
./s/v/b/MyThird
./s/v/MySecond
```

I would like it to be in this order:

```
./MyFourth
./s/MyFirst
./s/v/MySecond
./s/v/b/MyThird
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: python, ruby, perl ... ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/120701/650405

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you mean by "directory order", this should help:

```
find -name 'M*' -printf '%p\t%d\n' | sort -n -k2 | cut -f 1
```

It prints the files sorted by their depth in the directory tree.

Comment: unfortunately that separates the listing of a directory's contents and its subdirectories.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ find . -name 'M*' | awk -F/ '{print NF,$0}' | sort -k1,1n -k2 | cut -d' ' -f 2-
./MyFourth
./s/MyFirst
./s/v/MySecond
./s/v/b/MyThird
```