# unix "find" command native sorting order

Tags: unix, sorting, filesystems, find

If I use the find-command (no options except -name) - which is the order the output will be sorted in?

My own investigation showed it's neither alphabetically nor datetime-ly.

Searched the man pages, but I couldn't locate anything related to this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`find` command traversing the files and directories as they appeared in file system.

**Test:**

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*' 
ls -Ul
```

Here,

-U  - do not sort; list entries in directory order

Comment: Ok, so now I try to figure out what "directory order" means - or maybe you now?

Comment: found [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13451/what-is-the-directory-order-of-files-in-a-directory-used-by-ls-u)

Answer (score 1):

Hope [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9582059/find-command-listing-results-in-directory-order) will help. If not, you can always grab the find command algoritm because linux is open source, to see what exactly he does. note you will need some c knowledge. type in your distro and i'll find you the code

Comment: ...and by the end of the week I'll be [recompiling kernel](http://xkcd.com/456/)

Debian GNU/Linux 6.0.5 (squeeze)

Comment: http://packages.debian.org/source/squeeze/findutils -- I can look at it only tomorrow