# Iterating through directories and checking the file's size

Tags: python

I want to iterate through directories, and subdirectories, and check each file for a filesize. If it matches the defined filesize, it will be deleted.

I know, that i have to use os.walk, but i'm not quite sure, in which way.

The code i used for directory listing is :

```
import os
path = "C:\\Python27"
i=0
for (path,dirs,files) in os.walk(path):
    print files
    i=i+1
    if i>10:
        break
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Directory listing in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/120656/directory-listing-in-python)

Comment: you really should try out something before asking for help

Comment: I'm able to list all the directories and files, but i want to check for a particular filesize in each directory.

Comment: os.path.getsize function is your friend then. Just call `os.path.getsize(yourfilepath)` to return the size in bytes

Comment: Thanks! Got it working using os.path.getsize().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
import os

for root, dirs, files in os.walk('/path/to/dir', topdown=False):
    for name in files:
        f = os.path.join(root, name)
        if os.path.getsize(f) == filesize:
            os.remove(f)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked! 
What if i also wanted to check for a filename in the directory same as the directory name. Suppose, checking a file named mydir.txt inside the directory mydir.

Comment: @RobertShane it's all the same, add another condition something like `if root.endswith(name[:name.rindex('.')]):`

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
from __future__ import print_function # => For Python 2.5 - 2.7
import os

def delete_files_with_size(dirname, size):
    for root, _, files in os.walk(dirname):
        for filename in files:
            filepath = os.path.join(root, filename)
            if os.path.getsize(filepath) == size:
                print('removing {0}'.format(filepath))
                os.remove(filepath)
```

Like you said, [os.walk](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.walk) is the way to go for this sort of thing. `os.walk` returns a tuple containing the root path, a list of directories, and a list of files. Since we're not interested in directories, we use the conventional `_` variable name when unpacking the return value.

Since the filename itself doesn't include the path, you can use `os.path.join` with `root` and `filename`. [os.path.getsize](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.getsize) will return the size of the file, and `os.remove` will delete that file if it matches the size.