# Why does os.stat().st_size return 0 for dir?

Tags: python

So, I was reading RealPython '[Context Managers and Python's with Statement](https://realpython.com/python-with-statement/#traversing-directories)'.So when I try out the os.scandir() method in my python terminal :

```
with os.scandir('.') as entry:
  for it in entry:
    print(it.name, ' --> ', it.stat().st_size)


Output of the above code in the terminal:

demo.py --> 5749
fonts -> 0
images -> 0
music --> 0
notes.txt --> 13
templates --> 0
```

The size is printed correctly for the files yet why is that all the directory is listed as zero for some reason ?

The code from RealPython :

```
>>> import os

>>> with os.scandir(".") as entries:
...     for entry in entries:
...         print(entry.name, "->", entry.stat().st_size, "bytes")
...
Documents -> 4096 bytes
Videos -> 12288 bytes
Desktop -> 4096 bytes
DevSpace -> 4096 bytes
.profile -> 807 bytes
Templates -> 4096 bytes
Pictures -> 12288 bytes
Public -> 4096 bytes
Downloads -> 4096 bytes
```

Comment: What do you think it should return instead? Why?

Comment: `os.stat()` is a wrapper for low-level system calls that are implementation dependent. The `stat` standard library module [includes some tools to help interpret those results](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stat.html).

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I thougth it will return dir size as realpython example output, I included the output in my questions.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to generate directory size recursively in python, like du . does?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12480367/how-to-generate-directory-size-recursively-in-python-like-du-does)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Directories do not have a size. If you want to calculate how much space is used by a directory, loop through and aggregate the file sizes within

Comment: Can you please explain why the example from the RealPython(included in question now) show's otherwise ?

Comment: I missed a bit of my answer. I believe it depends on OS. Windows directories, for example, do not have a size.