# select files from path

Tags: python, file-io

I have files in particular path and need to select one by one base on namefile (yyyymmdd.faifb1p16m2.nc) where yyyy is year, mm is month, and dd is date. I made code like this :

```
results=[]
base_dir = 'C:/DATA2013'
os.chdir(base_dir) 
files = os.listdir('C:/DATA2013')
for f in files:
    results += [each for each in os.listdir('C:/DATA2013')
    if each.endswith('.faifb1p16m2.nc')]
```

What should I do next if I only select files for January, and then February, and so on. Thank you.

Comment: Use glob: http://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html

Comment: See answer I made to this post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two regexes:

1. `\d{4}(?:\d?|\d{2})(?:\d?|\d{2})\.faifb1p16m2\.nc`
2. `\d{8}\.faifb1p16m2\.nc`

Sample data:

1. 20140131.faifb1p16m2.nc
2. 2014131.faifb1p16m2.nc
3. 201412.faifb1p16m2.nc
4. 201411.faifb1p16m2.nc
5. 20141212.faifb1p16m2.nc
6. 2014121.faifb1p16m2.nc
7. 201411.faifb1p16m2.nc

The first regex will match all 7 of those entries. The second regex will match only 1, and 5. I probably made the regexes way more complicated than I needed to.

**You're going to want the second regex, but I'm just listing the first as an example.**

```
from glob import glob
import re

re1 = r'\d{4}(?:\d?|\d{2})(?:\d?|\d{2})\.faifb1p16m2\.nc'
re2 = r'\d{8}\.faifb1p16m2\.nc'

l = [f for f in glob('*.faifb1p16m2.nc') if re.search(re1, f)]
m = [f for f in glob('*.faifb1p16m2.nc') if re.search(re2, f)]

print l
print
print m
#Then, suppose you want to filter and select everything with '12' in the list m
print filter(lambda x: x[4:6] == '12', m)
```

As [another similar solution shows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13031989/regular-expression-using-in-glob-glob-of-python) you can ditch glob for os.listdir(), so:

```
l = [f for f in glob('*.faifb1p16m2.nc') if re.search(re1, f)]`
```

Becomes:

```
l = [f for f in os.listdir() if re.search(re1, f)]
```

And then the rest of the code is great. One of the great things about using [glob](http://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) is that you can use `iglob` which is just like glob, but as an iterator, which can help with performance when going through a directory with lots of files.

One more thing, here's another stackoverflow post with an overview of [python's infamous lambda feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890128/python-lambda-why). It's often used for the functions `map`, `reduce`, `filter`, and so on.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now it works, but I still have problem. I will put it in next question

Comment: @user3346361, be sure to upvote the answers and mark them as correct. What's your other problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can do :

```
x = [i for i in results if i[4:6] == '01']
```

It will list all file names for January.
Assuming that your all files of same format as you have described in the question.

Answer (score 0):

To validate filenames, you could use [`datetime.strptime()` method](http://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
from datetime import datetime
from glob import glob

suffix = '.faifb1p16m2.nc'

def parse_date(path):
    try:
        return datetime.strptime(os.path.basename(path), '%Y%m%d' + suffix)
    except ValueError:
        return None # failed to parse


paths_by_month = [[] for _ in range(12 + 1)]
for path in glob(r'C:\DATA2013\*' + suffix): # for each nc-file in the directory
    date = parse_date(path)
    paths_by_month[date and date.month or 0].append(path)

print(paths_by_month[2]) # February paths
print(paths_by_month[0]) # paths with unrecognized date
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
from os import *
results = []
base_dir = 'C://local'
chdir(base_dir)
files = listdir(base_dir)
for f in files:
    if '.faifb1p16m2.nc' in f and f[4:6] == '01': #describe the month in this string
        print f
```

Comment: @user3346361, be sure to upvote the answer and mark it as correct.