# Why is * in glob not matching to 0 or more chars preceding it?

Tags: python

I have three files in a folder - `stage-utah`, `stage1-utah`, `stage2-utah`. I use `glob` to get it expanded to the list. But with the regular expression `stage[12]*-utah`, I was expecting it will be expanded to all the files in the dir, as `*` matches to zero or more occurrences. But it expands to only `stage1-utah` and `stage2-utah`.

What is wrong in my expression?

```
>> stagedir = glob.glob("./stage*")
>> stagedir
['./stage1-utah', './stage2-utah', './stage-utah']

>> stagedir = glob.glob("./stage[12]*")
>> stagedir
['./stage1-utah', './stage2-utah']
```

Comment: You're confusing globs and regex. In globs, `*` matches 0-n of any character (equivalent to regex `.*`). Globs normally don't support what you're trying to do, though you could maybe do `stage*-utah` if that works for your case.

Comment: You can refer this for using regex in glob.glob: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13031989/regular-expression-using-in-glob-glob-of-python