# specify more than one pattern with glob - python

Tags: python, glob

Let's say I have files

```
bla_foo.txt
bla_Foo.txt
bla_bar.txt
xyz_Bar.txt
foo_bla.txt
```

is it possible to specify several patterns with `glob`? 
For example how can I select only `*Foo.txt`, `*foo.txt`, `*bar.txt` and `*Bar.txt`?

I know how to select only `*Foo.txt` and `*foo.txt` with `glob('*[Ff]oo.txt')`. But what if `*bar.txt` and `*Bar.txt` are also acceptable? Is this even possible with `glob` or will I have to create two globs

```
glob('*[Ff]oo.txt')
glob('*[Bb]ar.txt')
```

Comment: I'm assuming you're on a *nix based system?

Comment: @user3483203: Yes

Comment: glob doesnt support multiple pattern matching, you either grab everything and filter using regex, or perform two searches: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13031989/regular-expression-using-in-glob-glob-of-python