# How to print to the path of the file in python using glob

Tags: python, file, glob

I want to find the file name and then print the path of that file using python. My program runs successfully as follows.

```
from pathlib import Path
import glob
import os


for file in Path('<dir_address>').glob('**/*some_string*.*fastq.gz'):
    print(file)
```

It print the paths of all the files having some_string matching in its name in the .

Now I want to define an argument in place of `some_string` as follows.

```
file_name="abc"   

from pathlib import Path
import glob
import os


for file in Path('<dir_address>').glob('**/*file_name*.*fastq.gz'):
    print(file)
```

It doesn't give any output. My questions is how to give this sub_string as a variable in a program which will bring the files path of all the files having this specific sub_string in their name.

Comment: Have you considered using regex, as opposed to glob - as mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13032338/6340496)?  Then, you can use the `re.compile()` function to store the compiled regex into a variable, as you've asked.

Comment: I need confirmation, what you want is all file path of all filenames with the substring of _abc_ ? Am I right?

Comment: yes. All files path with a substring abc

Comment: you have string so use string function like string formatting `f'**/*{argument}*.*fastq.gz'` or for older Python `'**/*{}*.*fastq.gz'.format(argument)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you need:

```
from pathlib import Path
import glob
import os

file_name="abc"   
for file in Path('<dir_address>').glob(f'**/*{file_name}*.*fastq.gz'):
    print(file)
```

In the f-string `{filename}` gets replaced by the string of the variable `filename`.