# python glob to match a wider range

Tags: python, range, wildcard, glob

Trying to match files on disk that either end with .asm,ASM, or with some 1/2/3 digit extension like - .asm.1/.asm.11

My python code is-

```
asmFiles = glob.glob('*.asm') + glob.glob('*.ASM') + glob.glob('*.asm.[0-9]') + glob.glob('*.ASM.[0-9]')
```

How do I match the file **'.asm.11'** as my code can only match the first three?

Thanks

Comment: Try `glob.glob('*.asm.[0-9]*')

Comment: See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13031989/regular-expression-usage-in-glob-glob-for-python) on solving this with regex.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using Python regex and list comprehension:

```
import re

files = ['foobar.asm', 'foobar.ASM', 'foobar.asm.1', 'foobar.ASM.11', 'foobarasm.csv']

asm_pattern = '\.(asm|ASM)$|(asm|ASM)\.[1-9]$|\.(asm|ASM)\.[1-9][1-9]$'

asmFiles = [f for f in files if re.search(asm_pattern, f)]

[print(asmFile) for asmFile in asmFiles]
```

The last element from list files is an edge case I thought about to test the search pattern. It does not appear in the result, as expected.