# How to use the dir/s command in Python?

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, subprocess

**Background**

I use the command `dir/s` in batch files all the time. But, I am unable to call this using python. **NOTE:** I am using Python 2.7.3.

**Code**

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["dir/s"])
```

**Error Message**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    subprocess.call(["dir/s"])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 493, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 896, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

I have tried changing the quotations but nothing has worked.

How would I call the `dir/s` module using `subprocess`?

Comment: Why don't you use `os.listdir` (in a loop)?

Comment: @t-8ch It's easier to use `os.walk()`

Comment: @IonutHulub neither of your codes worked. I was unable to get the directory listing.

Comment: Guys - please check your code before you write it. Nothing has worked so far. :(

Comment: @xxmbabanexx Perhaps you should pay more attention to what you are reading. I didn't post any code, I just mentioned a mathod that you could use to get the job done. Look it up in the manual to see how it works.

Comment: @lonuthulub what I meant was that when I tried to use `os.walk` in a loop, it did not work. The second was not related to you.

Comment: What is the reason for all of the -1's? What can I do to improve the question, even though it has already been solved?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python execute windows cmd functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29925978/python-execute-windows-cmd-functions)

Answer (score 7):

How about

```
subprocess.call("dir/s", shell=True)
```

Not verified.

Comment: Don't use `shell=True` if you don't need to - `subprocess.call(["cmd", "/c", "dir", "/s"])` is better.

Comment: @Piotr Dobrogost why is that better? Sure, this is a simple example, but in general isn't it best to write a single string formatted like the shell expects?

Comment: @tdelaney because shell=True is in general not so secure as shell=False. "Invoking the system shell with shell=True can be a security hazard if combined with untrusted input. "

Comment: @zzk When I run the code, it simply returns `0`, without printing the directory. What is the reason for this.

Comment: @xxmbabanexx replace "call" with "check_output"

Comment: @zzk How would I get the directories for the `D:\\` Drive? Also, why did the original code return `0`? Lastly, what is the difference between `call` and `check_output`? Thanks for your help!

Comment: @zzk why does that freeze my computer?

Answer (score 3):

This is a lot different than what you're asking but it solves the same problem. Additionally, it solves it in a pythonic, multiplatform way:

```
import fnmatch
import os

def recglob(directory, ext):
    l = []
    for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(directory):
        for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, ext):
            l.append(os.path.join(root, filename))
    return l
```

Comment: When I did this, the error message told me that `directory` was not defined. I am also assuming that `ext` wouldn't work either. Sorry for being such a n00b, but could you please write the entire thing?

Comment: You need to invoke this function with 2 arguments - directory path and the extension for the files you need to glob. Example: `recglob('C:\foo\bar', '.baz')`

Comment: @Tuxdude How do I get the global name `fnmatch` to work? Also, could I get a listing of all of my files by doing `".*"`? Would that be possible in any way what-so-ever? Thank you *so* much for the help.

Comment: @xxmbabanexx: Add an `import fnmatch` at the beginning of the script. Likewise you'll also need another line with `import os`.

Comment: @martineau I thought that `import os` was outdated. I know that there are exceptions. Is this one of them?

Comment: @xxmbabanexx: Not exactly sure what you mean by "outdated". I only mentioned it because you seemed unaware that you'd need to `import fnmatch` in order to use it and the same logic applies to `os`'s functions.

Comment: awesome! that's what i was looking for

Answer (score 1):

You need a space between `dir` and `/s`. So break it into an array of 2 elements. Also as carlosdoc pointed out, you would need to add shell=True, since the `dir` command is a shell builtin.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["dir", "/s"], shell=True)
```

But if you're trying to get a directory listing, make it OS independent by using the functions available in the `os` module such as `os.listdir()`, `os.chdir()`

Comment: I don't think that's it. dir is a built in command (there is no dir.exe)

Comment: @carlosdc - Thanks, I've added shell=True now, so even builtins should work.

Comment: @carlosdc None of those worked. I am interested in making it platform-independant though. How would I use the `os` functions?

Comment: In the Windows shell/console you don't need a space between `dir` and the `/s`.

Comment: Use a string when shell=True and list when shell=False.

Comment: @xxmbabanexx the platform independent way is to use os.walk() or os.listdir(). You can google for samples because there are few tricks to know.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the answer. To list *all* directories in a directory (e.g. `D:\\`, `C:\\`) on needs to first import the `os` module.

```
import os
```

Then, they need to say that they want to list *everything.* Within that, they need to make sure that the output is printed.

```
for top, dirs, files in os.walk('D:\\'):
    for nm in files:       
        print os.path.join(top, nm)
```

That was how I was able to solve it. Thanks to [this.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/120695/1993598)

Comment: This doesn't answer your original question.

Answer (score -1):

As it's an inbuilt part of the command line you need to run it as:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call("cmd /c dir /s")
```

Comment: Not even close! You are trying to run a shell command, but using the non-shell list syntax and leaving shell=False.

Comment: @tdelaney: Actually is fairly close and will work if changed slightly to `subprocess.call(["cmd", "/c", "dir", "/s"])`.

Comment: @martineau - there is a huge difference between calling a program directly (use a list) and calling it through a shell (use a string and set shell=True). Subprocess trips a lot of people up... but maybe I did bark a bit loud. Your hybrid (call the shell explicitly instead of shell=True) has me scratching my head too! I think I'd prefer subprocess.call("dir /s", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE) as the example.

Comment: @tdelaney: I didn't say it was an optimal approach, only that with a minor change that it would work. I beginning to wonder if maybe you just tend to exaggerate things, because AFAIK there's not much difference between using `shell=True` and calling it yourself, as it gets called either way -- although I suppose some might consider the former arguably more explicit.

Comment: This also works for me so I'm unsure why it didn't work for some people. I think shell=True isn't required because it's explicitly calling cmd as part of the command - though that may be the better way to write it.