# Python execute windows cmd functions

Tags: python, windows, function, command-line

I know you can run Linux terminal commands through Python scripts using subprocess

```
subprocess.call(['ls', '-l'])    # for linux
```

But I can't find a way to do the same thing on windows

```
subprocess.call(['dir'])         # for windows
```

is it possible using Python without heavy tinkering?

Should I stick to good old fashioned batch files?

Comment: `ipconfig` is a Windows command. This should work (and it does on my computer).

Comment: why cant you do the same on windows? That is a windows command. Also if you want the output use `check_output("ipconfig")`

Comment: `subprocess.call(["ipconfig"])` works for me in windows ...

Comment: wait ipconfig is a terrible example

Comment: ok there, this is the one i was trying but can't get it to work

Comment: You can use `shell=True` `check_output("ipconfig",shell=True)`

Comment: Some Windows commands are built into the shell, such as `dir`. You need to run the command process itself: `'cmd.exe /c dir'`. Edit: or do as @PadraicCunningham suggests.

Comment: If you are just looking to get a list of files, you should be using `os.listdir` or maybe `glob.glob` rather than shelling out to do a `dir`.

Answer (score 4):

dir is not a file, it is an internal command, so the shell keyword must be set to True.

```
subprocess.call(["dir"], shell=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
import os

os.system("windows command")
```

ex: for date

```
os.system("date")
```

Answer (score 1):

Almost everyone's answers are right but it seems I can do what I need using os.popen -- `varStr = os.popen('dir /b *.py').read()`

Comment: The documentation for `os.popen()` states: *Deprecated since version 2.6:* This function is obsolete. Use the [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) module. Check especially the [Replacing Older Functions with the subprocess Module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess-replacements) section.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, to get a directory listing, you should rather use [`os.listdir()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html?highlight=os%20listdir#os.listdir). If you invoke `dir` instead, you'll have to parse its output to make any use of it, which is lots of unnecessary work and is error-prone.

---

Now,

`dir` is a `cmd.exe` built-in command, it's not a standalone executable. `cmd.exe` itself is the executable that implements it.

So, you have two options (use [`check_output`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html?highlight=popen#subprocess.check_output) instead of `check_call` if you need to get the output instead of just printing it):

- use `cmd`'s `/C` switch (execute a command and quit):

  ```
  subprocess.check_call(['cmd','/c','dir','/s'])
  ```
- use `shell=True` [`Popen()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html?highlight=popen#popen-constructor) option (execute command line through the system shell):

  ```
  subprocess.check_call('dir /s', shell=True)
  ```

The first way is the recommended one. That's because:

- In the 2nd case, `cmd`, will do any shell transformations that it normally would (e.g. splitting the line into arguments, unquoting, environment variable expansion etc). So, [your arguments may suddenly become something else and potentially harmful](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#security-considerations). In particular, if they happen to contain any spaces and `cmd` special characters and/or keywords.
- `shell=True` uses the "default system shell" (pointed to via `COMSPEC` environment variable in the case of Windows), so if the user has redefined it, your program will behave unexpectedly.