# How to find what files are in a folder

Tags: python, directory

I am writing a function that is recieving a folder path as an arguemnt. I want her to add into a dictionary what's inside the folder (like dir in CMD)

How can I do this ?

Thank you in advance,
Iliya

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk or http://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html

Comment: Look at the `os` module in the standard library. In particular the `os.listdir` function is equivalent to Windows' `dir` command.

Answer (score 1):

```
import os
print os.listdir('/tmp')
```

Similar Topics:

[Directory listing in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120656/directory-listing-in-python)

Also, I use [os.path](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html) and [glob](http://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) a lot while [manipulating file system path](http://docs.python.org/2/library/filesys.html). 
You might want to check it out.

Comment: Writing an answer and linking a question that clearly shows the fact that this question is a duplicate sounds a bit incoherent to me. You should have marked this question as duplicate of "Directory listing in Python" and, eventually adding some more information as comment.