# Extract names of files from a directory in python

Tags: python, file

How to extract the names of all the files in a directory in python

Comment: `import os; a_list_of_files_or_directories = os.listdir('/path/to/directory')`

Comment: You could have googled that simply...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Directory listing in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/120656/directory-listing-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below show all files in your path:

```
import os
files = os.listdir("your/path/")
```

Note, `listdir` not distinguish directories, files, links. Use [`os.path.isfile`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.isfile) and similar functions. Also, here many useful for `path`-works ([one](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os), [two](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html)).

Answer (score 1):

```
import os
filelist = os.listdir('../path/to/your/directory')
print filelist
```