# zip several files in python using loop

Tags: python, loops, zip

How can I zip multiple files using one loop in python?

I tried this but It gives me a error:

```
from zipfile_infolist import print_info
import zipfile
import fileinput
import glob
import os

for name in glob.glob( '*.xlsx' ):
    zf = zipfile.ZipFile('%(name)s.zip', mode='w')
    try:
        zf.write('%(name)s')
    finally:
        print 'closing'
        zf.close()
    print
    print_info('%(name)s')
```

This is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Fatt-DELL-3/ser.py", line 10, in <module>
    zf.write('%(name)s')
  File "C:\Program Files\IBM\SPSS\Statistics\22\Python\lib\zipfile.py", line 1031, in write
    st = os.stat(filename)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system can not find the file specified: '%(name)s'
```

Comment: Sorry for my code. I don´t know write code in this site

Comment: 1.  Remove all the back ticks.  2. All code needs to be indented by at least 4 spaces.

Comment: (1) you can use block code by highlighting the section and clicking the `{}` button. (2) you don't need a new line spacing for each line of code...

Answer (score 2):

If you have a look at [Python's string formatting documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting), you're using a `mapping` type of operation whenever your string includes something like `'%(name)s`.  For that, you need to follow it with a mapping object like a dict, eg:

```
'%(name)s' % {'name':name}
```

You need to add this to every place where you've put '%(name)s'

So these lines:

```
zf = zipfile.ZipFile('%(name)s.zip', mode='w')
zf.write('%(name)s')
print_info('%(name)s')
```

should be written as:

```
zf = zipfile.ZipFile('%(name)s.zip' % {'name':name}, mode='w')
zf.write('%(name)s' % {'name':name})
print_info('%(name)s' % {'name':name})
```

Comment: Thanks very much! In this syntaxe compress the directory too, but I'd like compress only the file. You know how I do this? Thanks

Comment: You have directory names that end in `.xlsx`???  If you want only files, you probably want to traverse the directory differently (eg. see answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/120656/directory-listing-in-python) )