# upload files from dropbox to googledrive using python

Tags: python, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am trying to upload all the files in my dropbox to google drive , for now I am able to upload a single file from my dropbox if i mention the filename. how do I get all the file names from drop box? 
FILENAME = "C:/Users/RAM/Dropbox/Apps/dropboxfiles/file_dropbox.txt"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Directory listing in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/120656/directory-listing-in-python)

Comment: Since the dropbox files are on your hard drive, just list them.