# How to detect if image name is different but image is same in php

Tags: php, file, image-processing

I am trying to validate while putting images in my server

1.If the image names are different but the image is same then do nothing.

How can I detect that

My code looks something like this

```
        if (file_exists($ficherof)) {
            $x=file_get_contents($ficherof) ;
            if($imagen['sha1']!=sha1($x))
            {
                //do something

            }
        }
        else
//here I have to check if the file name is different but the files are same then donot upload
        file_put_contents($ficherof, $contenido);
```

Comment: get both file contents and compare, use `sha1_file()` to compare, much faster.

Comment: @Daan sorry for the confusion its an Image , so what should i do in that regards

Comment: There is a nice answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29253608/1685196).

Comment: @Michel does this work same with he images also . I updated my question

Answer (score 5):

Checking the `sha` sum of two images in order to compare them is NOT correct! You can have two identical files with different `sha` sums - because the date/time can be  embedded in the EXIF data, or the PNG headers, or the TIFF tags.

The way to do it correctly is in my answer... [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29385890/how-to-compare-two-imagefile-from-two-different-files-in-python/29388205#29388205)

Watch this. I create 2 IDENTICAL black squares and compare them:

```
convert -size 256x256 xc:black 1.png
convert -size 256x256 xc:black 2.png
diff [12].png
Binary files 1.png and 2.png differ
```

Why are they different? Because the date is in them:

```
identify -verbose 1.png 2.png | grep date
date:create: 2015-04-03T13:31:30+01:00
date:modify: 2015-04-03T13:31:30+01:00
date:create: 2015-04-03T13:31:33+01:00
date:modify: 2015-04-03T13:31:33+01:00
```

What if I create a 256x256 black square GIF and an identical 256x256 black PNG?

```
convert -size 256x256 xc:black 1.png
convert -size 256x256 xc:black 1.gif
```

and look at them, they are different sizes, and will clearly have different checksums

```
ls -l 1*
-rw-r--r--  1 mark  staff  392  3 Apr 13:34 1.gif 
-rw-r--r--  1 mark  staff  279  3 Apr 13:34 1.png
```

but ImageMagick correctly tells me there are ZERO pixels different

```
convert -metric ae 1.png 1.gif -compare -format "%[distortion]" info:
0
```

Of course, if you compare `sha` sums and they are identical then the images are the same. All I am saying is that the images may be identical even though their checksums differ.