# Python: How to recursively move files that are inside folders?

Tags: python, file, move, subdirectory

I have this Python script that moves all files in a specified directory with a specific file extension. But if the files are located in subdirectories, they won't be moved. How do I move those files too?

```
import os
import shutil

dest = "/home/thee/Videos/"
sourcePath = raw_input("Enter file location: ")
filetype = raw_input("Enter file type (ex: .mp4): ")

source = os.listdir(sourcePath)

print "Moving all " + filetype + " files from " + sourcePath + " to " + dest

for files in source:
    if files.endswith(filetype):
        shutil.move(os.path.join(sourcePath,files), os.path.join(dest,files))
        print sourcePath + files
```

Comment: Use `os.walk` instead of `os.listdir`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Directory listing in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/120656/directory-listing-in-python)

Comment: @kindall It returns an error if I do that: if files.endswith(filetype):
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'endswith'

Comment: Well, you do have to change the rest of your code too... `walk` is not a drop-in replacement for `listdir` obviously, as can be seen by looking at [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk).