# Python: Script to access top level subdirectories only

Tags: git, python-2.7, scripting

I'm trying to develop a script to iterate through a directory that holds about 60 git repositories. I would like to use Python to enter just the FIRST subdirectory (the repositories), copy in a file from a known, constant path, commit and push.

Mainly I need help figuring out how to access JUST the repositories and not go any deeper into the .git directory or the code projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For python file/directory listing you could read this:

[Directory listing in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120656/directory-listing-in-python)

For Python interacting with Git, you can give a try to this project:

https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython

or simple use external process and manipulate the repository through git itself:

[Calling an external command in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python)