# how to import excel files from two folders in python

Tags: python, pandas

I initially have a code that is working in merging files in one folder. However, the work expanded to merge files in two folders. I edited the code to add first the list of files in two folders. That part is working but will not work in the actual for loop part. I am thinking this could be because of the current working directory but I do not know how to change that part. Here is my code so far:

```
files1 = os.listdir(folder1) #i just replaced the path with folder1
files2 = os.listdir(folder2) #i just replaced the path with folder2
files = files1 + files2

df = pd.DataFrame()         #creating an empty dataframe
for f in files:             #for loop in extracting and merging the files
    data = pd.read_excel(f)  
    df = df.append(data, sort=False).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can fix this code by adding folder names to file names:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

folder1 = 'folder1/'
folder2 = 'folder2/'

files1 = ["{}{}".format(folder1,file) for file in os.listdir(folder1)]
files2 = ["{}{}".format(folder2,file) for file in os.listdir(folder2)]
files = files1 + files2

print(files)

df = pd.DataFrame()         #creating an empty dataframe
for f in files:             #for loop in extracting and merging the files
    data = pd.read_excel(f)  
    df = df.append(data, sort=False).reset_index(drop=True)
```

And move it to a helper function, like Alex suggested in order to make code better.

**EDIT:**
Code with a helper function:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

def listdir_fullpath(d):
    return [os.path.join(d, f) for f in os.listdir(d)]

folder1 = 'folder1/'
folder2 = 'folder2/'

files1 = listdir_fullpath(folder1)
files2 = listdir_fullpath(folder2)
files = files1 + files2

print(files)

df = pd.DataFrame()         #creating an empty dataframe
for f in files:             #for loop in extracting and merging the files
    data = pd.read_excel(f)  
    df = df.append(data, sort=False).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you change your code design a little bit. Make a list of all the folders and iterate on them and load the files in the loop. You can use this code for as many folders as you want

```
import os
from pathlib import Path

def merge_files_in_folder(folder):
    df = pd.DataFrame()

    for excel_file in os.listdir(folder):
        data = pd.read_excel(folder / excel_file)
        df = df.append(data, sort=False).reset_index(drop=True)

    return df


folders = ['folder1', 'folder2']
df = pd.DataFrame()

for folder in folders:
    data = merge_files_in_folder(Path(folder))
    df = df.append(data, sort=False).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're right: "os.listdir" only lists filenames of the files in defined folder ([Python 3 Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir)).

Since it os.listdir returns a list, you could use a helper function ([like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/120948/12412421)) to prepend the path to every list item.