# Why I'm getting FileNotFoundError even though the file exists in the directory?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tkinter, list-comprehension

> This is my code

```
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import *
import os
root = Tk()
root.withdraw()

folder_selected = filedialog.askdirectory()

list_files = os.listdir(folder_selected)

print(list_files)
```

> My code was working fine when I was reading from files in the same directory. But after selecting a folder path using Tkinter and list of files in that folder using listdir, I tried to read from those files. But instead I'm getting an error.

```
for file in list_files:
    f =  open(file,'r')
    all_Lines = f.readlines()
    vList = [formatter(lines) for lines in all_Lines if isVariable(lines)]
    print(vList)

   mList = [formatter(lines) for lines in all_Lines if isMethod(lines)]
   print(mList)
```

Here is the Error:-

[image]

Comment: `os.listdir()` only lists the files in a folder. To load them you need the complete path of the file. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120656/directory-tree-listing-in-python

Comment: @ScootCork , very helpful ! Thanks ! :)